# How to exit from Flutter after calling flutter activity from android?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am calling a flutter module/aar from my Android app. I used an intent which will be created after a button press which starts a flutter module/aar.
Its working fine but I can't find any documentation guiding how to exit from flutter and start some other android intent or navigate back to previous android screen buy doing say a button press (without pressing back button).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SystemNavigator.pop()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html) method:

> Removes the topmost Flutter instance, presenting what was before it.
>
> On Android, removes this activity from the stack and returns to the previous activity.